# Source extractor "cannot open final.fits"

Tags: fits

I try to use the source extractor and want to analyse a file called "final.fits". I already got files like default.conv, default.nnw, default.param, default.sex in the same directory, where I excecute the SoEx. Thats why I'm not sure why it shoud't work. Has someone an idea?
Final.fits was created by Midas from a .bdf file, which is an average from some other files.
Desc final.fits:
NAXIS 2
NPIX: 1877 1875
Start 78 131
Step 1 1
Ident aberage frame
LHcuts -10 3000 -266 620692

I have no idea where to start.
I intalled the programm by myself on my laptop. Could this cause a problem?